# À quel point le fait de ne pas précéder un nom de famille par son titre est-il acceptable ?

Tags: usage, société, noms-de-famille

Il m'est arrivé à plusieurs reprises d'avoir affaire à des personnes qui m'ont repris alors que je mentionnais quelqu'un sans mettre M., M<sup>me</sup> ou M<sup>lle</sup> devant son nom (ceci à l'oral).

Personnellement, je ne trouve pas cela spécialement choquant, d'autant plus que je vois souvent cette façon d'écrire sur des articles, même faisant mention de personnes connues ou occupant des fonctions menant généralement à un certain respect (par exemple des choses comme "*Sarkozy* était un président" ou encore "Pour beaucoup, *Jobs* était un CEO exceptionnel").

Alors, question, jusqu'à quel point est-il acceptable de ne pas précéder le nom de famille de son titre quand on mentionne quelqu'un n'étant pas présent dans la conversation ?

EDIT : Ne serait-ce pas simplement en fonction du contexte et de la façon dont on parle de ces personnes ensuite ? Si par exemple je parle de quelqu'un sans précéder son nom de son titre mais que je parle tout de même d'une façon respectueuse, n'est-ce pas acceptable ?

Answer (score 3):

L'usage est d'utiliser le patronyme seul quand la personne est célèbre (ex: politiques, sportifs, artistes, etc.) ou fait partie d'un groupe de subordonnés ou de pairs (ex: les élèves d'une classe).

Il est de manière générale plus respectueux de faire précéder le nom par le prénom ou le titre de civilité.

Il faut aussi noter que « mademoiselle » tends à disparaître au profit de « madame » pour désigner une femme quelle que soit sa situation matrimoniale.

Comment: Réponse synthétique mais complète, merci. Concernant le « mademoiselle », il est effectivement [interdit par la loi dans les formulaires administratifs](http://www.service-public.fr/actualites/002616.html?xtor=EPR-140). Il dérangeait certaines de mes amies dans ce contexte car il forçait à révéler une information autre que le sexe, mais il demeure toujours apprécié à l'oral.